# Unable to get output variable of Oracle procedure using Sql linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have created a Heterogeneous connection between `SQL Server` and `Oracle` and tried to call a oracle procedure from `SQL Server`.I got below error when i tried to execute the procedure.

> OLE DB provider "ORAOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "TESTORACLE"
>   returned message "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character
>   string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "TESTUSER.PKG_TEST", line 1744".
>   Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Procedure SQLSTOREDPROCEDURE, Line 75
>   [Batch Start Line 0] Could not execute statement on remote server
>   'TESTORACLE'.

I have gone through the code and found that the error occurs only when assigning the value for OUT parameter.

**SQL SERVER PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SQLSTOREDPROCEDURE]  AS 
DECLARE @op_update_status Nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @op_error_message Nvarchar(500)
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SET XACT_ABORT ON;
 SET @p_process_name = 'PROCESSNAME'
 EXECUTE ('BEGIN  TESTUSER.PKG_TEST.P_SET_VALUES(?,null,?,?); END; ',@p_process_name,@op_update_status ,@op_error_message ) AT [TESTORACLE];  

 RETURN 0;
END
```

**ORACLE PROCEDURE**

```
PROCEDURE  P_SET_VALUES  (   p_process_name      VARCHAR2,                                   
                             p_processed_dt      DATE,                                    
                             op_update_status OUT VARCHAR2,
                             op_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
                         ) AS

 v_update_status VARCHAR2(50);
 v_error_message VARCHAR2(500);

 BEGIN


    USER2.PKG_TEST2.P_SET_VALUE  ( p_process_name,'TEST STATION',p_processed_dt,v_update_status,v_error_message) ;
     op_update_status := v_update_status;
     op_error_message := v_error_message;


END;
```

Then I googled and alter the procedure by specifying the `OUTPUT` parameter in `SQL Server`.

```
EXECUTE ('CALL  TESTUSER.PKG_TEST.P_SET_VALUES(?,null,?,?)',@p_process_name,@op_update_status OUTPUT ,@op_error_message OUTPUT) AT [TESTORACLE];
```

After that I get below error,

> Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Procedure
>   SQLSTOREDPROCEDURE, Line 75 [Batch Start Line 0] Could not execute
>   statement on remote server 'TESTORACLE'.

Please help me to overcome this error.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Even though Sql server return a error message, oracle procedure was called. Checked with dummy insert in application log table.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong string length in your SQL Server proc, look at this:

```
v_update_status VARCHAR2(50);
v_error_message VARCHAR2(500);


DECLARE @op_update_status Nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @op_error_message Nvarchar(500)
```

Original oracle parameters are of length 50 and 500 bytes, but you use `NVARCHAR` and your SQL Server variables are 100 and 1000 bytes long (UCS-2 uses 2 bytes to store each symbol)

Update: I've found Oracle data types and saw that `varchar2` is not unicode data type, Oracle uses nvarchar also, so all what you need is to change your `Nvarchar` type to `varchar` in your SQL Server code